# Writing my own arduino driver

Tags: arduino, usb

I'm currently making my own version of an Arduino Leonardo and want a way to differentiate between it and the Leonardo, I have my own bootloader with edited descriptors to change the pid ,vid , name and company but it shows up as a Leonardo if I don't change the pid and vid, and shows up as a USB Serial port if I do change them.

I'm thinking I need to write my own driver for it to have the correct name, is there any resources that can point me in the right direction?

I tried editing arduinos but it fails on install, I think the security file has something to do with that.

Comment: Do you have code you want to share - or specifics that describe your problem?

Comment: I want my board to show up as whatever I name it and it shows up as a USB Serial port or Arduino Leonardo. I'm  just editing arduino's files so there isn't any real custom code. I THINK it references the drivers I have installed for the Leonardo when I set the pid and vid for that board, however when I change the pid and vid it shows as a usb serial port instead, I think this is because it can't find another driver for that specific pid and vid.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy a code signing certificate an re-sign the CAT file that comes with the drivers.  See [my article on the subject](http://www.davidegrayson.com/signing/).

Alternatively, you can just switch to Windows 10, which has a new driver called usbser.inf.  This driver should automatically recognize the virtual COM ports on your board and configure them to be used with usbser.sys, so you don't need a driver.

Comment: Awesome I appreciate it, I'm using 10 and it works fine , I just wanted to rename it so it was easier to identify, definitely going to check out your article .

Comment: If you user usbser.inf, every serial port for your device will be named "USB Serial Device", unfortunately.  It doesn't use your USB string descriptors.